# Global variable value is not present inside function

Tags: php

I have the following function to create and display a filled rectangle inside an image using PHP:

```
$GLOBAL['feed_background'] = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/feed_background.jpg');

function test() {
    $white = imagecolorallocate($GLOBAL['feed_background'], 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($GLOBAL['feed_background'], 10, 10, 50, 50, $white);
}
```

For some reason mentioning the `$GLOBAL` variable this way doesn't work and the rectangle doesn't appear.

Making it like this however works:

```
$feed_background = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/feed_background.jpg');

function test() {
    global $feed_background;
    $white = imagecolorallocate($feed_background, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($feed_background, 10, 10, 50, 50, $white);
}
```

What's wrong with the first block of code?

Comment: $GLOBAL**S**...

Answer (score 0):

I had a syntax error in my code. `$GLOBAL` should be `$GLOBALS`. Stupid me!